# hide() direction of image in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, hide, show, direction

I have problems with jquery direction of hide() when putting my html page in ember view:
Jquery code:

```
$("#slide1").hide({direction: right}, 500, function(){
        console.log("case 1");
        $("#slide2").toggle({direction: "right", distance: 460}, 500);
        $("#arowImage").hide({direction: "right"});
        $("#arowImage2").show({direction: "right"});
    });
```

after click on the arrow I can see in console 
"Uncaught ReferenceError: right is not defined"

If I write {right} or {direction: "right") in line 1 (not {direction: right}) I got in console information: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } "

If I delete "{direction: right}" the animation is working, but of course without directions.

Toggle, hide and show in line 3, 4 and 5 are working but the direction (right) are not.

I think ember is blocking this code, so how can I execute this code?

Comment: It will be helpful if you could add a JSBIN

Answer (score 0):

In line 1, it should be `direction: "right"` and not `direction: right`

Comment: If I write {right} in line 1 (not "{direction: right}") I got in console information: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }". That "}" is comming from "{right}". "direction: "right"" is also not working

Comment: Try giving the double quotes only for the word "right" like you have done in other lines. See if that works.

Comment: {right}, {direction: right}, {directon: "right"} are not working

Comment: @polischmen did you try giving a transition like slide?
for example: $("#slide1").hide( "slide", { direction: "right" }, 500 );

Comment: Also I tried. I got in console "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function ". I am also sure, that it is not a problem with spellmistake or JS but JS vs ember.